# Android - How to position view according to anchor point in view

Tags: android, android-view

In the GoogleMaps api, we're able to set an anchor point on a map Marker, which positions the marker relative to a specific point in the image we're using as the marker.  I want to achieve something similar using just a regular view (an ImageView in my case).  I tried messing with the gravity in the xml of the ImageView, but that's not achieving what I want.  Basically I want to be able to set

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

but have the view on which this is set to center in the parent according to the top right corner of the view.  How can I accomplish this without the use of a hacky solution like editing the margins?

Answer (score 0):

Man, just put your `View` inside `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`.

Comment: yeah? that's it? seems like there should be some kind of attribute which does what im describing? that's kind of what i meant by "hacky" solution. thanks for the suggestion anyways

Comment: Year. If you will put, u will get your gravity option.

Comment: yeah, i was aware of this option, but was hoping for something a little nicer.  bummer...

Comment: Yes, you would think there would be something similar to [`CALayer`'s `anchorPoint` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint), but I don't think there is.